# graphing a trig function to find its limit.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am just starting to learn about limits and am  trying to solve the problem $\lim_{\theta\to 0}f(x) = \sin (2\theta)/\theta$

I thought the best way to solve this would be to substitute values that are closer and closer to $0$ for $\theta$ and report the result that the output seems to be approaching. When I do this, I get the answer .0349. My textbook reports the correct answer as .01745, which is my answer divided by 2.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The answer should be $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your calculator is in degree mode. the answer you are getting is $\pi/90.$
switch it to radian mode and see what happens.

Comment: My answer is 2. This still differs from the answer given in the textbook, being .01745

Comment: your answer is correct.